# Cómo puedo simular un endpoint en codepen

Tags: jsfiddle

JSFiddle e su documentación tiene una forma de [simular llamadas asíncronas](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/async-requests).

Por [ejemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cevxq/6/):

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
      json: '{"n":"1","txt":"No apostrophe"}'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#ajax-json').html(data.n);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert('there was an error');
    },
    dataType: 'json'
  });

  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/echo/html/',
    data: {
      html: '<b>HTML</b>'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#ajax-html').html(data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert('there was an error');
    },
    dataType: 'html'
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ajax-json"></div>
<div id="ajax-html"></div>
```

Fuera de jsfiddle daría error, pero en el sitio regresa lo que le especificamos en data.

¿Existe alguna forma de lograr eso mismo en codepen.io?

Comment: Creo que codepen.io no tiene esa característica, pero puedes seguir usando la de jsfiddle usando como url `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/jsfiddle.net/echo/json` o `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/jsfiddle.net/echo/html`.

Comment: No lo tiene, pero si lo que querés es obtener un JSON, podés usar otro sitio gratuito como https://next.json-generator.com/ para generarlo y llamarlo desde codepen.io

Comment: Excelentes opciones, agréguenlas comom respuestas por favor

Comment: De hecho la respuesta seria "no tiene", ya que las serian opiniones